# can anyone explain to me how bufferevent ( in libevent) works for non-blocking sockets?

Tags: c, libevent

The documentation for libevent 2.0 isn't easy to understand.  Can anyone point me to a tutorial?

Comment: Excellent. Tumbleweed...

Answer (score 3):

http://www.wangafu.net/~nickm/libevent-book/

is a great tutorial on libevent, with loads of examples. As a bonus, it's written by [Nick Mathewson](http://www.wangafu.net/~nickm/), one of the two maintainers of the libevent project.

For bufferevents, you can look at [the basics](http://www.wangafu.net/~nickm/libevent-book/Ref6_bufferevent.html) as well as [the advanced bits](http://www.wangafu.net/~nickm/libevent-book/Ref6a_advanced_bufferevents.html).

Comment: Ah - this is the documentation i was referring to... would you say it was a tutorial? have you tried and tested it yourself - it wasn't really that clear to me.

Comment: This site is what I used to learn how libevent works. I still don't understand everything, but it's better than anything else out there, and got me to the point where I can use libevent and know how most of it works. Have you bothered reading the bufferevent pages? There are at least 3 example programs - in particular, the watermark example and basic http client example.